# The Arrow in pop up menu has gone and icons in the menu bar on the top of the screen disappear after clicking

Tags: display

Could anybody tells me how to solve this problem? It's very frustrating to see this from time to time in my laptop. I was trying to post a question on Apple Community, and I don't know why their website won't let me do so.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting for a disk/file permission issue. And OSX doesn't have permission to access the file/image (hopefully not somehow deleted) So use Disk Util to repair and verify your drive.

Comment: @BarryCarlyon it doesn't work. But thanks.